# VS Code Launch Configuration for Node as SUDO

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, launch

I need to remote debug a node express script, actually i'm doing it from a remote-ssh session.
Unfortunatly some functionalities, as the access to FS, dont't work as expected unless I run the node with sudo privileges.

**How can I run the Node.js script as sudo from within Visual Studio Code?**

This is my actual Launch configuration

```
{
    "name": "NodeJS Local Server",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.js",
    "request": "launch",
    "args":["tmparg"],
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
    ],
    "type": "node"
},
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.